# PDF.js - how can I get info per characters but not by chunk of text?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

By using [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) info per chunk of text can be get as follows but some space-separated characters are incorrectly processed as a chunk. A pdf that I want to process uses monospaced font so it's convenient if I can get info per characters which allows me to detect space by calculating their coords. Is there any method of parameter to do that?

```js
const base64 = "data:application/pdf;base64,******";
const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: atob(base64.replace(/^.*,/, '')) });
const pdfDocument = await loadingTask.promise;
const page = await pdfDocument.getPage(1);
const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
console.log(textContent.items);
// [
//   {
//     "str": "Sample",
//     "dir": "ltr",
//     "width": 78.39999999999999,
//     "height": 9.8,
//     "transform": [
//         9.8,
//         0,
//         0,
//         9.8,
//         58.8,
//         721.0800000000004
//     ],
//     "fontName": "g_d0_f1",
//     "hasEOL": false
//   },
//   ...
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you need to implement it in the source code of pdf.worker.js.

In method "buildTextContentItem", you can get every char of a text chunk, including its unicode and transform, then you can push them into an array and return in text item.

Example:

```
textChunk.charsArray.push({
  char: glyph.fontChar,
  unicode: glyph.unicode,
  transform: textChunk.prevTransform,
  str: textChunk.str.join("")
})
```

Add above code to the last of that method. Tested in version: 3.8.162

Answer (score -2):

You can use the getTextContent() method in PDF.js to extract the text content of a PDF page as a stream of characters, rather than chunks of text. You can then iterate over the characters and perform any desired processing, such as extracting information about each character. Here is an example

```js
// Load the PDF document
pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfUrl).promise.then(function (pdfDoc) {
  // Get the first page
  pdfDoc.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
    // Get the text content as a stream of characters
    page.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {
      // Iterate over the characters
      for (var i = 0; i < textContent.items.length; i++) {
        var char = textContent.items[i];
        // Perform any desired processing on the character
        console.log(char.str, char.width, char.height);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately you are just showing how to iterate infos about chunk of text. Please be sure that `char.str` is not actually a char.